# TeXstudio needs "manual cleanup" when syntax error

Tags: texstudio, syntax, logging

The following minimum example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

When I compile this with TeXstudio, everything works fine.

Let's say now, I'm writing `\chapte{Sample}` instead of `\chapter{Sample}`. The next time I am trying to compile TeXstudio consequently cancels with:

> Undefined control sequence. \chapte

Then I notice the error and change it back to `\chapter{Sample}`. The syntax now should be fine again, but when I try to compile again, the above mentioned error remains and it's no more possible to compile again. The **only** possibility I found so far is

- to (maually) delete the .log-file,
- to restart TeXstudio
- and then compile again.

I assume, that this isn't the right behaviour... What am I doing wrong or what is configured wrong? I am using TeXstudio  2.12.6 with MiKTeX on Windows.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you perhaps go into a bit more detail on your second compilation? E.g. what error message shows up that alerts you to the fact that "it's no more possible to compile again"?

Comment: I could solve it on my own - see my answer. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem on my own.

The wrong configuration was, that for whatever reason the standard compiling procedure call was set to  `txs:///makeindex | txs:///pdflatex`. I changed it to only `txs:///pdflatex` and now it works. The `makeindex` caused the problem.

Thanks anyway!